# method to iterate on table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table on website that I need to check if requirements are fulfilled using Selenium.

Number of rows is dynamic - one day it is 3 and one day is 5 rows.
I would like to write a method that will check (compare numbers) if **Current value is (greater than or equal to Minimum Value)** and **(smaller than  or equal to Maximum Value in each row)**.

I wrote this method but it is only applicable for one row and checks *only minimum.*

**Code**

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"po-carts\"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]")
protected WebElement minimumREQ1;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"po-carts\"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")
protected WebElement actualREQ1;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"po-carts\"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]")
protected WebElement maximumREQ1;

public void checkRow1() {
    if (minimumREQ1.isDisplayed()) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 1) {
            String ov1 = minimumREQ1.getText();
            String ov2 = actualREQ1.getText();
            String ov3 = maximumREQ1.getText();
            if (ov1.equals("-")) { ov1 = "0"; }
            if (ov2.equals("-")) { ov2 = "0"; }
            if (ov3.equals("-")) { ov3 = "0"; }
            double doubleOV1 = Double.parseDouble(ov1);
            double doubleOV2 = Double.parseDouble(ov2);
            double doubleOV3 = Double.parseDouble(ov3);
            if (doubleOV2 < doubleOV1) {
                Integer number = firstnumber + i;
                String stringNumber = number.toString();
                increaseProduct1.clear();
                increaseProduct1.sendKeys(stringNumber);
            } else {
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Use xpath :- //table[@class='qor-table']//tbody/tr. This will return you all the rows. Then you can perform operation on any td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I manage to do this myself.

```
    public void checkQOR() {
    int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"po-carts\"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr")).size();
    for (int j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        WebElement elementMIN = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"po-carts\"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[" + j + "]/td[3]"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementMIN));
        double doubleMIN = Double.parseDouble(elementMIN.getText().replaceAll("-", "0"));
        WebElement elementCUR = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"po-carts\"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[" + j + "]/td[4]"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementCUR));
        double doubleCUR = Double.parseDouble(elementCUR.getText().replaceAll("-", "0"));
        WebElement elementMAX = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"po-carts\"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[" + j + "]/td[5]"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementMAX));
        double doubleMAX = Double.parseDouble(elementMAX.getText().replaceAll("-", "0"));
            if ( doubleMIN > 0 && doubleCUR < doubleMIN && (doubleCUR < doubleMAX || doubleMAX==0 )) {
                Integer number = firstnumber + i;
                String stringNumber = number.toString();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(increaseProduct1));
                increaseProduct1.clear();
                increaseProduct1.sendKeys(stringNumber);}
                else if (doubleMAX > 0 && doubleCUR > doubleMAX) {
                    //DO SMTH
                }
                else {
                    break;
            }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 List<WebElement> webElement = 
 driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class="qor-table"]//tbody/tr"));

for (int i = 1;i<=webElement.size();i++){

System.out.println("Minimum "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class="qor- 
table"]//tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[3]")));

System.out.println("Current "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class="qor- 
table"]//tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[4]")));

System.out.println("Maximum "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class="qor- 
table"]//tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[5]")));

}
```

Hope this help!